# getting an EventListener to store text when page loads

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I am new to programming and JavaScript.  I'm trying to add an event listener so that when a user enters some text, it is stored in local storage and is there on the page when reloaded.  I have set up a function `diaryText()` to get a value, turn it into a text item and store it.  The event listener has been added, but I don't think I have got the code correct.

```
// Make diary data item
function makeItem(type, data) {
  var itemObject = { type: type, data: data };
  return JSON.stringify(itemObject);
}

// Add a text entry to the page
function addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry) {
  // Create a textarea element to edit the entry
  var textareaElement = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
  textareaElement.rows = 5;
  textareaElement.placeholder = "(new entry)";

  // Set the textarea's value to the given text (if any)
  textareaElement.value = text;

  // Add a section to the page containing the textarea
  addSection(key, textareaElement);

  // If this is a new entry (added by the user clicking a button)
  // move the focus to the textarea to encourage typing
  if (isNewEntry) {
    textareaElement.focus();
  }

  // Make an event listener to save text when it changes:
  // ...get the textarea element's current value
  function diaryText() {
    var data = textareaElement.value;
    // ...make a text item using the value
    //    (demonstrated elsewhere in this file)
    var item = makeItem("text", data);
    // ...store the item in local storage using the given key
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);
  }

  // Function to connect event listeners and start the application
  function initialize() {
    // A rough check for local storage support
    if (!window.localStorage) {
      // This could be more elegant too
      document.querySelector("main").outerHTML =
        "<h1>Error: localStorage not supported!</h1>";

      // Stop the demo
      return;
    }

    // Connect the event listener to the textarea element:
    textareaElement.addEventListener("onblur", diaryText);

    // Connect the input file selected event listener
    // (note this may not trigger if you repeatedly select the same file)
    var inputElement = document.querySelector("#image input");
    inputElement.addEventListener("change", processFile);


    // Create some demonstration items
    createDemoItems();

    // Update the page to reflect stored items
    showEntries();
  }

  // Connect event listeners and start the application when the page loads
  window.addEventListener("load", initialize);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<main>
  <section id="text" class="button">
    <button type="button">Add entry</button>
  </section>
  <section id="image" class="button">
    <button type="button">Add photo</button>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: what does the function "makeItem" do - could you include it?

Comment: where is "dataInput", the actual textarea where you would try and enter text to save.

Comment: oh yes sorry. I forgot to change that - it was supposed to be textareaElement i think.  Although that still doesnt get the eventListener to fire up

Comment: you have this line:  dataInput.addEventListener("onblur", addTextEntry);  where is the var "dataInput" defined?

Comment: oh yes sorry, that was not suppose to be in there.  This is the code i have entered. 
 textareaElement.addEventListener("onblur", diaryText); .  It says that textareaElement and diaryText are not defined.  I have tried data.addEventListener as well and that does not work either.

Comment: In that case I think I see the problem.  You define "textareaElement" inside of the function "addTextEntry" - when you reference "textareaElement" from your "initialize" function it has not been defined yet, and it's not in the proper scope.  Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: uncaught ReferenceError: textareaElement is not defined.

Comment: So now you are not calling addTextEntry() at all?  That seems to be the wrapper function that hold everything - it's the thing that creates the textareaElement, but you need to pass in "(key, text, isNewEntry)". I mean, even your initialize function is stuck inside of the addTextEntry() function.  If you would like I can put together a quick example, loosely based on the code you have provided, to show you how to properly read and write to localStorage, so text is retained on page refresh.

Comment: Hi Kyle, oh thank you very much for all your help.  I have been having issues with whether to wrap it up in a separate function or the addTextEntry().  I think thats where the confusion is.  If you could put something together for me, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: excellent! If you want me to put together a quick example of what you are trying to accomplish, let me know and I'll post it in an answer.

Comment: Yes please Kyle. A quick example would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the code snippet here is blocked from using lcoalStorage.  However, you can check it out on jsfiddle, or copy and paste it into your own html file and open it in browser.

https://jsfiddle.net/81no5jxh/

```html
<style>textarea{display: flex;}</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="button">save</button>

<script>
    var $textarea = $("#textarea");
    var $button = $("#button");

    function initialize(){
      if(!window.localStorage){return alert("Error: localStorage not supported!");}

      var _startingMessage = window.localStorage.getItem("message_key") || "";
      $textarea.val(_startingMessage)
      $button.on("click", _handleButtonClick);
    }

    function _handleButtonClick(){
        localStorage.setItem("message_key",$textarea.val())
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Kyle.  Thanks for putting that together for me.  I will certainly copy and paste it and see how i get on.  Cant thank you enough.